# How to return few string from threads and concat it in C++/CLI

Tags: multithreading, winforms, c++-cli

how to return few Strings from threads and link it to one String ?
I use CLI/C++, threads in windows forms. This code should divide message from user to n(nThreads) texts and in each thread should encipher message.
Finally it must concat all results to one.

Actually I did something like this:

```
public: ref class ThreadExample
{
public:
    static String^ inputString;
    static String^ outputString;
    static array<String^>^ arrayOfThreads = gcnew array <String^>(nThreads);
    static int iterator;

    static void ThreadEncipher()
    {
        string input, output;
        MarshalString(inputString, input);
        output = CaesarCipher::encipher(input);
        outputString = gcnew String(output.c_str());
        arrayOfThreads[iterator] = outputString;
    }
```

Function where I use threads:

```
        array<String^>^ ThreadEncipherFuncCpp(int nThreads, string str2){
            array<String^>^ arrayOfThreads = gcnew array <String^>(nThreads);
            string loopSubstring;
            messageLength = str2.length();
            int numberOfSubstring = messageLength / nThreads;
            int isModulo = messageLength % nThreads;
            array<Thread^>^ xThread = gcnew array < Thread^ >(nThreads);
            int j;
            //loop dividing text to threads
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++)
            {
                j = i;
                if (i == 0 && numberOfSubstring != 0)
                    loopSubstring = str2.substr(0, numberOfSubstring);
                else if ((i == nThreads - 1) && numberOfSubstring != 0){
                    if (isModulo != 0)
                        loopSubstring = str2.substr(numberOfSubstring*i, numberOfSubstring + isModulo);
                    else
                        loopSubstring = str2.substr(numberOfSubstring*i, numberOfSubstring);
                }
                else if (numberOfSubstring == 0){
                    loopSubstring = str2.substr(0, isModulo);
                    i = nThreads - 1;
                }
                else
                    loopSubstring = str2.substr(numberOfSubstring*i, numberOfSubstring);


                xThread[i] = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&ThreadExample::ThreadEncipher));
            }

            auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++){
                ThreadExample::iterator = i;
                ThreadExample::inputString = gcnew String(loopSubstring.c_str());
                xThread[i]->Start();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++){
                xThread[i]->Join();
            }
            auto elapsed = chrono::system_clock::now() - start;
            long long milliseconds = chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();
            cppTimer = milliseconds;
            arrayOfThreads = ThreadExample::arrayOfThreads;
            delete xThread;
            return arrayOfThreads;
        }
```

Comment: Your `ThreadExample` class should not have any static members. 1) Fork each thread with its own object of `ThreadExample`. 2) keep a reference to those `ThreadExample` objects. 3) after all threads have finished (after `->Join()`), extract the data out of those `ThreadExample` objects.

Comment: And what happened when you executed that code? Please don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess here and say that the program ran without error, but your output was blank.

The reason the output is blank is because of the static class initializer. This is executed earlier than you think it is: As soon as you reference the class in any way, the static initializer runs. Therefore, when you try to execute `ThreadExample::inputString = "Some example text. Some example text2.";`, the static class initializer *has already run*, and your array of threads is set.

To fix this, move that code out of the static initializer, and into the method where you create the threads.

Also, a more general note on C++/CLI: If you're trying to learn C++, please don't use C++/CLI. C++/CLI is **not** the same thing as C++. C++/CLI has all the complexities of C++, all the complexities of C#, and some complexities of its own thrown in for good measure. It should be used when it's needed to interface .Net code to C++ code, not as a primary development language.